# Async await api return undefined react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, material-ui

I don't really understand why, if I use asyn await directly to call api and I get data immediately when the component mount inside useEffect(), but when I call getLevels() from my selectApi.js, it return undefined when the component mount. See code below:

`App.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getLevels } from "./selectApi";
export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadLevels();
  }, []);

  const loadLevels = async () => {
    //Working fine if I use call await API directly in this file
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3040/v2/feedback/levels");
    console.log("Data ----> ", res); //working fine
    setOptions(res.data)
    
    /* Not working if I import getLevels() from selectApi.js
    getLevels().then((res) => {
      console.log("Data --> ", res); //return Data --> Undefined when component load
    });*/
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Select</h1>
      <select>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        {options.length > 0 &&
          options.map((item) => (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`SelectApi.js`

```
const ENDPOINT_URL = "http://localhost:3040/v2/feedback/";

export const getLevels = async () => {
  await axios.get("http://localhost:3040/v2/feedback/levels");
};
```

> Working fine when I call api directly in App.js

[image: Working fine when I call api directly in App.js]

[image]

Comment: You don't `return` anything in `getLevels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in selectApi.js

```
export const getLevels = async () => {
  return await axios.get("http://localhost:3040/v2/feedback/levels");
};
```